# Inconsistency Between Approaches Solving System of Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, physics

This requires a bit of setup, so bear with me. I'm working through a physics problem. The physics itself is irrelevant, but the setup gives you a system of differential equations. The details in how I solve it are also not very important. My question pertains to the last part. You can skip ahead if you want; I only list my work to be exhaustive, in case it does matter. I'm reasonably confident that my work is right.

$$m\dot{v_x} = qE_0+\frac{q}{c}v_yB_0 \tag{1}$$
$$m\dot{v_y} = -\frac{q}{c}v_xB_0 \tag{2}$$

To solve this, I differentiate 2 and solve for $\dot{v_x}$:

$$v_x = -\frac{mc}{qB_0}\dot{v_y} \tag{3}$$
$$\rightarrow \dot{v_x} = -\frac{mc}{qB_0}\ddot{v_y} \tag{4}$$

Plugging this into 2, I get:

$$m(-\frac{mc}{qB_0}\ddot{v_y}) = qE_0+\frac{q}{c}v_yB_0$$
$$\rightarrow \ddot{v_y} + \frac{q^2B_0^2}{m^2c^2}v_y = -\frac{q^2E_0B_0}{m^2c} \tag{5}$$

The homogenous solution vs a choice of particular solution yields:

$$v_y = A\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + C \tag{6}$$

Differentiating (to check the validity of the homogenous solution) and plugging that into 4 to solve for the particular solution:

$$\ddot{v_y} = -\frac{q^2B_0^2}{m^2c^2}(A\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)}) \\ \rightarrow -\frac{q^2B_0^2}{m^2c^2}(A\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)}) + \frac{q^2B_0^2}{m^2c^2}(A\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + C) = -\frac{q^2E_0B_0}{m^2c} \\ \frac{q^2B_0^2}{m^2c^2}C = -\frac{q^2E_0B_0}{m^2c}$$
$$\rightarrow C = -\frac{E_0c}{B_0} \tag{7}$$

From here, the initial conditions are:

$$v_x(0) = v_y(0) = 0 \tag{8}$$

Combining $(6)$, $(7)$, and $(8)$:

$$v_y(0) = A\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}(0))} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}(0))} - \frac{E_0c}{B_0} \\ = A - \frac{E_0c}{B_0} = 0$$
$$\rightarrow A = \frac{E_0c}{B_0} \tag{9}$$

From here is the crux of the issue. I can now solve for $v_x$ in two different ways, **and this presents my issue.** The first way is using $(3)$:

$$v_y = \frac{E_0c}{B_0}\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} - \frac{E_0c}{B_0} \\ \rightarrow \dot{v_y} = -\frac{qE_0}{m}\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\frac{qB_0}{mc}\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} \\ \rightarrow v_x = -\frac{mc}{qB_0}(-\frac{qE_0}{m}\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + B\frac{qB_0}{mc}\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)})$$
$$\rightarrow v_x = \frac{E_0c}{B_0}\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} - B\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)}) \tag{10}$$

From $(10)$, it's plain to see that $B$ would be $0$. However, an alternative approach using $(1)$ yields a contradiction:

$$m\dot{v_x} = qE_0 + \frac{q}{c}v_yB_0$$
$$\rightarrow mv_x = qE_0t + \frac{qB_0}{c}\int(v_y(t))dt \tag{11} \\ = qE_0t + \frac{qB_0}{c}(\frac{E_0mc^2}{qB_0^2}\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} - B\frac{mc}{qB_0}\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} - \frac{E_0c}{B_0}t) + D$$
$$\rightarrow v_x = \frac{E_0c}{B_0}\sin{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} - B\cos{(\frac{qB_0}{mc}t)} + D \tag{12}$$

These two equations, $(10)$ and $(12)$, are the exact same aside from the integration constant $D$, which begs the question - should $(11)$ have contained the definite integral $\int_0^t(v_y(t'))dt'$ instead, but the above is still a solution to $(1)$ despite not being a solution to $(2)$. I get that the indefinite vs definite thing is the issue, here, but what is the explanation for how equation $(2)$ seemingly limits the possibilities for the solution to $v_x$ to specifically $D = 0$. I'm struggling to come up with an intuition for why that makes sense.

Comment: A solution to a system of equations must satisfy $all$ the equations. Thus, the condition that $(12)$ satisfies both $(1)$ and $(2)$ implies $D=0$, and you end up with a solution identical to $(10)$, as it should be. There is no inconsistency here.

Comment: Much obliged. I don't know why it was making me uncomfortable, but the way you've phrased it here has helped click things into place for me.